# #id and .subclass both are not working at a time

Tags: font-awesome

The below statements are HTML statements.  In this part, I directly want to increase the icon size of `fa` subclass of `skills` id. So how to make changes in CSS.

```
<section id="skills" class="container-fluid text-center">
  <!-- title -->
  <div class="title">
    <h1 class="display-4">Skills</h1>
    <div class="title-underline"></div>
    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- end of title -->
  <div class="row">
    <article class="col-sm-4">
      <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-3x"></i>
      <h2>Quality</h2>
      <p class="text-muted">am sit dolores.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block">Learn More</a>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `font-size` property.

```
<i class="fa fa-coffee fa-3x" style="font-size: 5em;"></i>
```